# How to find outliers in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, data-science, outliers

I wrote the following code to identify outliers, but I get the following error. Can you help me?

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
z = np.abs(stats.zscore(data))
print(z)
```

**can only concatenate str (not "float") to str**

Comment: Provide a sample of `data`.

Comment: And what line has the error? If it displays a callstack, show that too

Comment: It would be useful to have a sample of the data. Nonetheless, np.abs should be returning an array or a float. Therefore you need to use str(z) when concatenating it with another string for printing the results